# Given Sequence of Numbers find number of combinations

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I have the sequence of numbers $1,2,4,8,16,\ldots$. This is an infinite sequence. So my problem is that if I have any positive integer value, $x$, what are the possible ways that I can write $x$ as the sum of the sequence that I noted above.

For example, if $x=7$, then I would have the possible ways to be

- $1+1+1+1+1+1+1$
- $1+1+1+1+1+2$
- $1+1+1+2+2$
- $1+1+1+4$
- $1+2+2+2$
- $1+2+4$

So in this when $x=7$ we have $6$ possible ways. So basically, my question is that is there a way to generalize this for any value of $x$? If it is necessary to note, when $x=10$ there are $14$ possible ways.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A018819

Comment: @MarkBennet I have spent a long time looking through that, but I am having trouble seeing what the generalization is. The answer below says pretty much the same as what is on the webpage. Can you show me what it is that I am missing or not seeing?

Comment: I quoted it as a comment because it didn't fully answer the question, but the OEIS does tend to gather a vast amount of known information, so if the answer isn't there, it may not exist in the form you want. If you followed one of the links you'd get to https://oeis.org/A000123 which strips out the duplicate entries for $2n$ and $2n+1$ and gives the asymptotic rate of growth of the modified sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can always decompose $x-1$ and then add a single $1$; this gives $N(x-1)$ ways to write $x$.  If $x$ is odd, this is your only option, so $N(x)=N(x-1)$ for odd $x$.  On the other hand, if $x$ is even, then you can decompose $x/2$ and then double all the terms; this gives $N(x/2)$ additional ways.  So $N(x)=N(x-1)+N(x/2)$ for even $x$.  This simple recursion lets you calculate $N(x)$ for arbitrarily large values.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but what do you mean by $N(x)$? What does the function do exactly?

Comment: Can you give an example of how this works when x=7?

Comment: @user112123: $N(x)$ is the number of ways of expressing $x$ as a sum of powers of $2$. To keep this comment down to a reasonable size I’ll use $N(5)$. The possibilities are $4+1$, $2+2+1$, $2+1+1+1$, and $1+1+1+1+1$, so $N(5)=4$. Each of these ends in $+1$; drop that off, and you get the $N(4)=4$ possibilities for $4$: $4$, $2+2$, $2+1+1$, and $1+1+1+1$. Now $4$ can be obtained by adding a $+1$ to a decomposition of $3$: that’s where $2+1+1$ and $1+1+1+1$ come from, and it accounts for $N(3)=2$ cases. it can also be obtained from $2$ or $1+1$ by doubling each term; that’s where $4$ and ...

Comment: ... $2+2$ come from, and it accounts for $N(2)=2$ values: $N(4)=N(4-1)+N(4/2)=N(3)+N(2)$.